# Nginx 403 Forbidden error while using NFS-Shared Volumes on Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nfs, amazon-ebs

I am testing out the Shared Persistent Volumes on my Cluster. I have created an EKS cluster on AWS, I have installed NFS server on one of the nodes, created PV& PVC for the same. I am able to mount the volumes with multiple applications. But I am unable to access the html files from Nginx server as it throws **403 Forbidden Error.**

Below are the screenshot of my NFS -Server, nginx where my data mounted on it with permissions

[image]

[image]

I have deployed Nginx as Pod on my Cluster. Below are my Nginx configuration files

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

nginx pod logs

```
   *22 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/" is forbidden, client: 10.14.20.128, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1", host: "*.amazon.com"
    getuser?index=0 HTTP/1.1", host: "3.124.54.114:80"
    10.14.20.178 - - [07/Jun/2021:08:59:10 +0000] "GET /config/getuser?index=0 HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0" "-"
    2021/06/07 09:03:30 [error] 30#30: *1788 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/test1/" is forbidden, client: 10.14.21.153, server: localhost, request: "GET /test1/ HTTP/1.1", host: ".elb.amazonaws.com"
    10.14.21.153 - - [07/Jun/2021:09:03:30 +0000] "GET /test1/ HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36" "-"
    10.14.21.153 - - [07/Jun/2021:09:12:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1" "-"
    2021/06/07 09:12:30 [error] 30#30: *1953 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 10.14.21.153, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "35.157.4.133"
    10.14.21.153 - - [07/Jun/2021:09:12:30 +0000] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://35.157.4.133/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1" "-"
    2021/06/07 09:12:30 [error] 30#30: *1954 "/usr/share/nginx/html/HNAP1/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.14.21.153, server: localhost, request: "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "35.157.4.133", referrer: "http://35.157.4.133/"
    2021/06/07 09:55:33 [error] 30#30: *2729 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
    127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2021:09:55:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "curl/7.64.0" "-"
    2021/06/07 10:02:47 [error] 30#30: *2828 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
    127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2021:10:02:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "curl/7.64.0" "-"
```

Comment: change the file permission on NFS so that nginx can access it and serve it.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply !, if you see the screenshots attached i have 777 permissions on all the files

Comment: i am sorry i missed it just read main question. why don't you check the logs of nginx ingress controller pod ?

Comment: also try updating the service name in nginx config to `server_name  _;` instead of using the value of `Localhost`. https://github.com/harsh4870/Kubernetes-wordpress-php-fpm-nginx/blob/master/nginx-configmap.yaml

Comment: Hi Again!, I am neither using nginx ingress controller or nginc config_map file, Edit my question with logs for my nginx pod. is it mandatory to have configmap for nginx?

Comment: here logs clearly saying the `/usr/share/nginx/html/test1/" is forbidden` you go inside the nginx pod and try changing the permission instead of setting up at nfs once to debug the issue one time and verify

Comment: Hi , When i try to update the permissions on the files & folders i get the below error .chmod: changing permissions of 'test': Operation not permitted. Researching few blogs found to apply this command lsattr test/ then i am getting this error lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test/sample-nginx-minio.html

Comment: I am new to these things , can you redirect me to some blogs /documentation that can help me out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233437/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-nishar-sheik).

Comment: How did you configure the NFS server ?
Can you provide the `/etc/exports` file ?

Comment: I have Installed NFS server on my Ec2 instance & using the same instance details with my PV . below is my /etc/exports file                                                                         
#/nfs-share *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
#/nfs-share *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
#/pv/nfs/ *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)
/nfs-data *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)

Comment: Can you try `chown -R nobody:nogroup /nfs-data` command on the NFS side to remove restrictive permissions and then try again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. When you are installing NFS-server (Considering it as Master) on EC2 instances we have to make sure we are mounting the NFS server path on other EC2 instance (Considering it as a Client) & Applying relevant Chmod permissions we will be able to access the files via nginx